# bootstrap - avoid gap between controls when window gets maximized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to keep both the text input and the button input sticking together in following code. Right now, when the window gets maximized, there is space between the two controls, how to avoid this?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="sendmessage" id="sendmessage" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    ...
```

Comment: I have added a couple of tags hoping they make your question get some more attention

Comment: nobody has an idea? thought this would be a simple one..

Comment: So you can't wrap everything in a container div to prevent the expansion?

Comment: no it doesnt solve the problem. in jsfiddle it looks ok, but this is a simple view in a mvc 5 template project in vs2013. i am completely new to bootstrap & mvc 5. i think it's because of the header in visual studio default mvc 5 template. who can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i am a newbie when it comes to "modern UI techniques" and now i feel a little shame because i figured out that adding:

```
input[id=message] {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

in site.css solved the problem! :-)

Comment: actually this is a workaround, when max-width is not set to 100% there is always space between the input text and the button, i would be glad to learn how to make the send-button sticking right next to the input text regardless of the input text's width. like i wrote its just the default mvc 5 template with membership and its a really simple new view page on it. i edited the code above.